# Correct way to initialize const member in C++03

Tags: c++

I need to write some **C++03** code for a legacy environment. The following code compiles but the compiler (`g++ (SUSE Linux) 6.3.1 20170202 [gcc-6-branch revision 245119]`
) complains.

Code:

```
typedef unsigned char Key[100];

class A {
public:
    const Key key1 {0x1};
    const Key key2;

    A(): key2({0x1}) {};
};

int main() {
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
test.cpp:6:24: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
     const Key key1 {0x1};
                        ^
test.cpp:6:20: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
     const Key key1 {0x1};
                    ^
test.cpp:6:24: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
     const Key key1 {0x1};
                        ^
test.cpp: In constructor ‘A::A()’:
test.cpp:10:15: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
     A(): key2({0x1}) {};
               ^
test.cpp:10:20: warning: list-initializer for non-class type must not be parenthesized
     A(): key2({0x1}) {};
```

So what is the correct way (i.e. compliant with C++03) to initialize `const` array members?

Comment: That feature is not available in C++03, unless you make the member `static`

Comment: Even then, you can't initialize an array in-class.

Comment: @romeric So const members have to be static? That sounds unreasonable to me. Ultimately I want to have a class member that can only be modified by the initializer.

Comment: @qweruiop can you show more meaningful example? Otherwise why at all would you make private const not-static member of a class? You don't need to make it a class member at all, move it all to .cpp file better.

Comment: @Pavel okay, that's a good point. I meant `public`. I guess to make it static is also okay. After all, I'm just trying to understand what is doable and what's not.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 introduced the ability to initialize array members in the initializer list. This feature is needed to initialize array elements to a specific value other than zero. Since arrays can't be copied, providing an initialized arrays to copy from also doesn't work.

However, what *does* work is to wrap the array with a `struct` and to initialize a `const` member by copying such a `struct`. For example:

```
template <int Size>
struct array {
    unsigned char value[Size];
};
typedef array<100> Key;
class A {
    Key const key1;
    Key const key2;
    static Key make_key() {
        Key rc = Key();
        rc.value[0] = 0x1;
        // whatever else
        return rc;
    }
public:
    A(): key1(make_key()), key2(make_key()) {}
};
```

The initialization in `make_key()` merely resembles the initialization in the example (the first element initialized to `0x1`, all others to zero). Clearly, it can do do whatever else is needed, probably based on arguments forwarded from the constructor.

Comment: You could also use [boost::array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/array.html) for some [syntactic sugar](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73ad6a6072e2c8ba).